# Image processing Histogram equalization

Tags: image-processing, histogram

Why there is no change in histogram , if we equalize it twice ?

Comment: What is your understanding of histogram equalization? What does it aim to do with the image's histogram?

Comment: This is because equalization is an idempotent operation.  That is to say, if you equalize an image then any subsequent equalization will result in the exact same image (for most definitions of "equalization").